# HTML5 SQL Storage within a WebView on Android 4.1

Tags: javascript, android, html, storage

I'm trying to use HTML5 SQL storage from a web view under Android 4.1.1.

In a browser (on either desktop or android device) my code works fine but when I try to execute it into a Android's WebView then I get the following error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined

I read a lot on this topic but it's not clear if Android supports this feature. It seems it was well supported on Android v2.x but no longer since v4.x due to restrictions.

Do you know any information about that?

My is as below,
initing the webview:

```
webViewMenu = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMenu);
// Add javascripInterface to the webviews
webViewMenu.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
// Open webview with Chrome
webViewMenu.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String
databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2); // try to keep quota size as big as possible else database will not get created in HTML 5 app
}
});
WebSettings settingsMenu = webViewMenu.getSettings();
settingsMenu.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
settingsMenu.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```

Opening the database from JS:

`dbModels = openDatabase ("models", "1.0", "Demo Database", 2*1024*1024);`

Thanks for your help

Comment: wasn't webSQL was removed way before 4.1?

Comment: Sorry if my english is poor but I don't well understand what do you mean. Do you mean Web SQL support has already been removed from Android?

Comment: i thought it was removed, but when i checked this now it says it's only deprecated, not removed. sorry for the confusion and good luck.

Comment: Just a bit late..did you manage to solve it? I'm having a similar issue. Thanks